# Devise before_filter authenticate_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added an admin role to Devise by adding a admin attribute.

Could you tell me if this is the right way to create a before_filter that requires an admin user to be signed:

in any controller:

```
before_filter :authenticate_admin!
```

in application_controller

```
protected
  unless current_user.try(:admin?)      
    redirect_to :new_user_session_path      
  end
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Go with this approach

```
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter do 
    redirect_to new_user_session_path unless current_user && current_user.admin?
  end
```

This also ensures any guests are forced to sign in as well.  You don't need to modify the default method to force authentication just to access the instance method `admin?`

```
def admin?
  self.admin == true
end
```

My approach is to create a role attribute and check its string value against a set of intended roles - it's far more flexible this way rather than having to create many boolean attributes.

Comment: No need to define admin?, if the admin column is already a Boolean then you can just call user.admin? and it will automatically return true or false without having a admin? method in user.

Comment: Correct, however, for most of my apps I tend to store these as strings.  Combine this with an authorisation layer, i.e. CanCan, and it's easy to define levels of 'admin' prowess.  For a `boolean` column in the DB, you do not need to redefine the predicate method as I have shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the answer above (by Michael De Silva), I had an issue with the code he used. He wrote the path as a symbol (`:new_user_session_path`), but I needed it to be a regular path helper (`new_user_session_path`). Until I changed this, I was getting errors, saying the path was invalid. (I am running Rails 5.)

Hope this is helpful to others!