# How to allow only Admin (or some user) to edit the pages in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan, rolify

I have a scaffold Finances and I just realized that it can be edited by any logged in user by going to /finances/1/edit

I have installed activ_admin gem but I don't think it is what I need. How to make sure other than admin (or may be some users) no one can edit finances resource type- I

EDIT - I found https://github.com/EppO/rolify, is this best option or I still can do something better as it may be overkill ?

EDIT 1 - I went through this https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Tutorial and have assigned role "admin" to user = User.find(1), everything went well upto "ability.can? :manage, :all" in console, which shows TRUE for user 1 and false for other users. Now I am not able to figure out what to do ? I can still see all users being able to edit the page even though I have added "resourcify" in the finance.rb model. Any help ?

Comment: Did any of the provided solutions answer your question?

Comment: @zeantsoi - added some more info in the question. I am trying cancan + rolify method though still stuck

Comment: Have you put load_and_authorize_resource into your finance controller as suggested by https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I personally use rolify for my project and love it.. but to be honest this is super easy to achieve by simply adding a column "admin" to your User model and having it default to false. When you want a user to be an admin update the attribute to true and then require the User.admin==true to access the finances edit action... You can do this by redirecting the non-admin user from the controller (within the finances edit action)

By the way if you're using devise for auth check out [Devise before_filter authenticate_admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411577/devise-before-filter-authenticate-admin)

Comment: yes I am using devise, I see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-role, which is nice so should I use that or should go with rolify ? also can't I just use "if uid == 1"  or similar code in controller ?

Comment: Yeah, you could do it that way.. and yes, if you just have this simple case and no other need for roles in your site, I would just go with the devise wiki link method :)

Comment: Hi, I went through this https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Tutorial and have assigned role "admin" to user = User.find(1), everything went well upto "ability.can? :manage, :all" in console, which shows TRUE for user 1 and false for other users. Now I am not able to figure out what to do ? I can still see all users being able to edit the page even though I have added "resourcify" in the finance.rb model. Any help ? Thanks

Comment: So you've added this to your ability.rb file in app/models? if user.has_role? :admin
  can :manage, :all
else
  can :read, :all
end

Comment: Hey buddy, me again ... I did some digging .. check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096763/what-is-the-purpose-of-rolify

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how your models are set up, but lets say your `User` model has an admin column, you can do the following:

```
FinancesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :must_be_admin, only: :edit

  def edit
    ...
  end

  private

  def must_be_admin
    unless current_user && current_user.admin?
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Some message"
    end
  end
end
```

You can add any actions needed to the before filter, e.g. `before_filter :must_be_admin, only: [:edit, :destroy]`

Comment: Hi, I went through this https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Tutorial and have assigned role "admin" to user = User.find(1), everything went well upto "ability.can? :manage, :all" in console, which shows TRUE for user 1 and false for other users. Now I am not able to figure out what to do ? I can still see all users being able to edit the page even though I have added "resourcify" in the finance.rb model. Any help ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to add sensible user authorization without rolling your own solution, definitely check out [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). Also helpful is [this screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) by its author, Ryan Bates.

Comment: Hi, I went through this https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Tutorial which installs cancan + rolify and have assigned role "admin" to user = User.find(1), everything went well upto "ability.can? :manage, :all" in console, which shows TRUE for user 1 and false for other users. Now I am not able to figure out what to do ? I can still see all users being able to edit the page even though I have added "resourcify" in the finance.rb model. Any help ? Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with some code. It is difficult to diagnose what's going on without seeing what you're working with.