# What is the purpose of Rolify?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rolify

Hi I'm using rolify and have just realized that I'm not actually taking advantage of it's full potential.

At present I am doing things in my controller like re-routing users if `current_user.has_role? :whatever_role`, and allowing users if they have whatever other role...

Someone asked a question on stackoverflow about rolify and when I got to trying to answer it, I realized that I'm doing it wrong.

Now, here is where my confusion starts... Inside of ability.rb I have:

```
user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
if user.has_role? :consumer
  can :manage, Review
else
  can :read, Review
end
```

Now let's say I add the consumer role to a user:

```
x=User.last
x.add_role :consumer
# => #<Role id: 10, name: "consumer", resource_id: nil, resource_type: nil, created_at: "2013-04-18 23:00:46", updated_at: "2013-04-18 23:00:46">
```

Right, so the role is created. I can check this by doing:

```
x.has_role? :consumer
=> true
```

Now I would expect this to give management ability for reviews...

```
x.has_role? :consumer, Review
=> true
```

but not for other models... here I try products

```
x.has_role? :consumer, Product
=> true
```

Further, when I look at "resource roles querying" and try to query the applied roles for reviews I find no applied roles:

```
Review.first.applied_roles
=> []
```

Can someone please explain rolify to me. Thanks

Comment: I like reddit as a source of questions, but I **love** stackoverflow being the **authoritative source** of answers. So I've replicated a question that everyone may find it easier, sooner; and [posted my answer on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/1cn4ra/can_someone_please_explain_the_abilityrb_file/c9i7s55). If my answer is not viewed as favorable by him on reddit, I will link to any better response in an answer here, and then close this. Otherwise, I would love for his question to be answered here too, which I will then pass on to reddit.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

My answer, garnishing the question from [this reddit post:](http://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/1cn4ra/can_someone_please_explain_the_abilityrb_file/)

**Authentication** is establishing a `User` is who they claim to be.

**Authorization** is establishing that a `User` can perform a given action, be it reading or writing, after they've established their identity.

*Roles* are just common patterns of *authorization* across users: this `User` can be authorized *as such*, that `User` can be authorized *like this instead*.

The ingredient you're missing here is *Permissions*: a relationship between an established `Role` and some controller action.

`Roles` themselves make no promises about what action a `User` can perform. And remember--*authorization* is all about actions. `Roles` generalize what kind of `User` you're dealing with. They exist to keep you from having to query every `User` for a giant laundry list of `Permissions`. They declare: this `User` is a `Role`! Of course they have `Permission` to do that!

There are many types of `Permission`. You can store them in a database if you want your sufficiently *authorized* `Users` to be able to edit them, along with your `Roles` if those too ought to be configurable. Or, if your `User's` `Roles` are sufficiently static, you can manage `Permissions` in advance with Ruby code:

- When I want to have configurable `Roles` and `Permissions`, i.e. for a client application you're handing off to someone at completion of contract, I implement a `User :has_many Roles` and a `Role :has_many Permissions` with my own custom models, and then add a `before_filter :authorize` hook into my `ApplicationController`, and write an `authorize` method on it that knows how to martial these expectations, or render a 403 page for those people who insist upon manually entering urls to things they hope expose `actions` to things they oughtn't have access to.
- When I want to just have configurable `Roles`, I use [Ryan Bates' CanCan gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).
- When I want to have predetermined `Roles` and `Permissions`, I use [Rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify) in conjunction with [Nathan Long's Authority](https://github.com/nathanl/authority), to get delightfully flexible Class-based `Permissions` via Authorizer classes.

Both `Roles` and `Permissions` can be either class-based or instance-based, depending on your use-case. You can, say, with the abilities of `rolify` you've just discovered, decide that `Users` may only act as a `Role` in certain, instance-based circumstances. Or, general `Roles` of `User` may only be able to execute an *action* given the object they are trying to *action* is of a certain type.

To explore the permutation of these, assuming a blog application, following the formula

a `User` who is a/an `Role` `class/instance` can `action` a/an/all/any/that (`class/instance`) `Permission`:

- `Role` class and `Permission` class:

  A `User` who is an `Admin` can `delete` any `Post`.
- `Role` class and `Permission` instance:

  A `User` who is an `Admin` can `edit` all `Posts that they approved to be published`

  This would be easier if published posts had an `approved_by` field pointing to a `User` id. (Use a [state machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) [gem](https://github.com/troessner/transitions) for this sort of situation.
- `Role` instance and `Permission` class:

  A `User` who is `an Author of a Post` can `comment` on any `Post`

  Note that this sort of situation is rare, which is why there are no gems I've mentioned above to handle this situation, except for perhaps the ability to manage predetermined circumstances like `Rolify` and `Authority` in conjunction; or, if you must pass this decision on to your client, your own custom solution.
- `Role` instance and `Permission` instance:

  A `User` who is `an Author of a Post` can `edit` that `Post`.

TL;DR:

- `Rolify` is just for roles: grouping `Users` by `Permission`: access to a controller action. You have yet to decide how you are going to manage `Permissions`.

I hope this helps your understanding of `Rolify`'s position in the grand scheme of *authentication* and *authorization*!

Comment: So if "Rolify is just for roles" - what's the point using it? I use Devise + CanCanCan and define manually in the user.rb `def admin? admin end` then in ability.rb:

`if user.admin?
        can :manage, :all
      else
        can :read, :all`

Comment: @prograils It depends on how you want to write your authorization code (Devise is mostly just authentication). CanCanCan is a permissions library, and pairs well with Rolify. You have to ask yourself where the `user.admin?` method comes from. At first, that could just be a boolean attribute on user. As you grow into a non-binary roles system you would end up with tons of boolean flags on the model. If a user can have many roles too, your checks could get complicated fast. Rolify would let that become `user.has_role? :admin` and handle evolving complexity cleanly.

Comment: @prograils Rolify also allows a more fine-grained definition of roles. You can add roles for users for specific resource instances. For example you want user 'Joe' to have the role 'project manager', but only for the project 'XYZ'. [link](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify#6-resource-roles-querying)